# Creating profile using xml

Tags: php, html, xml

i want to create profile, i tried this way but it didn't worked..

`forum.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!file_exists('users/' . $username . '.xml')){

    header('Location: index.php');

    die;

}

?>
```

`header.php`

```
<?php

  $xmlFile = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlFile->load('users/'. $username .'.xml');

    echo $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;

?>
```

`user.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<user>

<name>yotam</name>

<lastname>dahan</lastname>

<password>73e872fc06e6de8562d1d040268dafc9</password>

<birthday>13.7.1999</birthday>

<country>Israel</country>

<gender>Male</gender>

<age>13</age>

<email>yotking789@walla.com</email>

<level>Admin</level>

</user>
```

I know the problem in   `$xmlFile->load('users/'. $username .'.xml');`  here but i can't make specific file because i got diffrent members every time and i cannot create each one page.

Any other way to get $username define in xml file load?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.. there might be a lot of security problems and your users personal data can be stoled

Comment: I know there are securty problem, but i dont might.. i only check the language values and using of xml.

Comment: The question is not formulated well I'm afraid. I could not figure out a) what your problem is (any error messages? expected vs. real output?) and b) what you are expecting from the community to solve the problem.

Comment: A "problem" here is that we can't assume $username is set when loading forum.php. I assume forum.php `include`s or `require`s the header.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as it should but what is the purpose here? If you are looking to store user details you should use a database such as MySQL which is then used to lookup this data instead of XML.

If you are getting errors then have you got PHP set to display errors? This might give you some idea what is going on.